# Analytic continuation of the $\arccos{x}$ function.

Tags: trigonometry

The other day I was asked about the value of $\cos(\arccos{\pi})$, which at first sight doesn't make a lot of sense. However, I decided to prove the following fact for all $x$.

$$ \cos(\cos^{-1}{x}) = x $$

To do this, however, I started with a very unusual first step, which is the reason I'm asking this question, since I feel my reasoning is circular here. I started with,

$$ \frac{d}{dx} \cos^{-1}{x} = \frac{-1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} = \frac{i}{\sqrt{x^2 - 1}} $$

Thus,
$$ \arccos{x} = \int \frac{i}{\sqrt{x^2 - 1}} = i\cosh^{-1} {x} + C$$

By defintion, here the constant $C$ is $0$

Thus, we obtain $$\cos^{-1}{x} = i\cosh^{-1} {x} \implies \cos{(\cos^{-1}{x})} = \cos{(i\cosh^{-1}{x})} = \cosh{(\cosh^{-1}{x})} = x $$

I think this is a very bad proof, but is it correct, or does it use circular reasoning? If yes, how can we fix that?

If this proof is outright wrong, I would like to know how do we prove it.

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=acos%28pi%29) seems to give $\cos^{-1}(\pi) = i\,\log(\pi+\sqrt{\pi^2-1})$ which is $i\, \cosh^{-1}(\pi)$, as in your results.  $\cos(i \,\cosh^{-1}(\pi))=\pi$, which completes your argument.

Comment: Note that any $z=2\pi n \pm i\,\log(\pi+\sqrt{\pi^2-1})\,$ with integer $n$ would satisfy $\cos(z)=\pi$.

Comment: But is my first step valid?

Comment: Saying $\frac{-1}{\sqrt{a}} = \frac{i}{\sqrt{-a}}$ is in my view risky: sometimes it will work and others not.  A similar argument might end up saying things like $\sqrt{-1}=\sqrt{\frac1{-1}}=\frac{\sqrt{1}}{\sqrt{-1}} \implies -1=1$ which clearly is not correct.